# How can I get a facebook users photo comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Currently when I look at my posts via the GraphAPI:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/posts/

Some posts have their "story" parameter truncated like this (note the ... after the word toe,):

```
{
"id": "xxxxxxxxx_yyyyyyyyyyyyy", 
  "from": {
    "name": "zzzzzz", 
    "id": "1234567890"
  }, 
  "story": "\"those things pivot at the toe,...\" on XYZ's photo.", 
  "story_tags": {
    "39": [
      {
        "id": 11111, 
        "name": "XYZ", 
        "offset": 39, 
        "length": 22, 
        "type": "user"
      }
    ]
  }
```

The above is a comment on a photo within facebook, so the graph api ids=http://.... approach that I have seen elsewhere on SO does not work.  When I try to pass in the id to the comment table via FQL I get no data returned.  I have all the appropriate permissions in the access token.

Overall what I am trying to achieve is a way to get everything a user has written/typed on facebook recently, so I need:

1.status updates - achieving this via:

```
select time, message from status where uid=me()
```

2.check ins - still working on this

3.comments on photos or working on other peoples status - still working on this and the reason for this post

Comment: did you ever get anywhere with this? this is driving me nuts. also, do you know how you get what the object (photo/status/whatever) it is the person was commenting on?

Comment: @MikeK - sorry mike - no progress or responses from here